# Android: Get events from "Visible" and "Invisible" calendars

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am using "Instances" method to query events from Android calendars. Based on the open source project, I would get Event from "Visible Calendars" only.
I want to get events from all calendars, ie both "Visible Calendars" and "Invisible calendars". I want to know how should I modify the code below to achieve the result.

By the way, I have tried "return Calendars.VISIBLE + "=0"; and i would get the event from Invisible calendars. But i just would not get both in the same time.

`public static String buildQuerySelection() {
        return Calendars.VISIBLE + "=1";     }
queryHandler.startQuery(0, queryData, queryUri, SQLEvqUtils.INSTANCES_PROJECTION, 
        SQLEvqUtils.buildQuerySelection(), null, SQLEvqUtils.AGENDA_SORT_ORDER);`